# An image of specific RGB value when imported as numpy array shows a different RGB value?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, rgb

I have an image by the name Red.jpg which is nothing but a rectangular image of plain red color of RGB value (255,0,0) generated using windows paint. Now I import the image using python as a numpy array using the code shown.

I see that the RGB values have changed.
What could be the reason to this?

```
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image


img= Image.open('Red.jpg')

imgArray = np.array(img)

print(imgArray)
```

I get the following result:

```
  [[254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  ..., 
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]]

 [[254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  ..., 
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]]

 [[254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  ..., 
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]
  [254   0   0]]]
```

I see that the RGB value has changed.

[Image generated in windows paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWbev.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible that the shade of red you're using is (237, 27, 36) and not (255, 0, 0)?

Comment: Perhaps post the image.

Comment: JPEG is **lossy**. Can you save it as a PNG?

Comment: Did you try saving as PNG?

Comment: @Mark Setchell - Actually I was trying to analyze an already existing JPEG image. Although the color is supposed to be perfect Red of RGB (255,0,0) as per the document, when I read the file as numpy array, it was not perfect red. So I tried out creating a red picture using paint and saw this problem. Now I know from you that JPEG has this problem.

Comment: @Apoorv - In paint I did use the color (255,0,0)

Comment: Ok, cool. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Thats the RGB values of Paint's default red.

The one you find as the 4th color in the pallette.

[image]

Saving it to jpeg changes the 28 to 27. Maybe due to compression.

The numpy values are correct.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you!